# How to override Oracle Apex to upload files

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

How do I override Oracle Apex to upload files? I get the error

```
Erro: 413 Request Entity Too Large
```

I have already changed in `nginx` and `tomcat` and nothing solves this, wouldn't interface have anything to help?

Version: 19C

Comment: Guys, what I meant is that my upload is limited and I would like to remove that limit, or increase it.

Comment: Error 413 is a web server issue, an HTTP error code, not an APEX error. What exactly did you change in nginx? Have you seen this? https://jasonyisong.wordpress.com/2020/12/08/import-apex-app-error-413-request-entity-too-large/

Comment: @pmba hello, 

I performed this procedure on nginx, but the error persists, even after restarting the service or oracle / apex

I made changes to tomcat but without success.


Thanks for help.